# Pass slicer value to another page from selected value to less or equal slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I Have two pages report, in the first page I have a bar char count of employee by department, in the second page I have a table with employee informations.

when I select a date (year) in the slicer which represent the Start date of the employee, I get the count of the employee start at the selected year by department,

I drill through to the detail page I get the information of the employee start at the selected year.

for now, all good.

What I want is when I push the drill through button, I want to see in the detail table in the next page with the employee start **before** or at the selected year.

I tried to add a year slicer with less or equal option in the second page and synchronize it with the slicer in the first page, but both were synchronized to less or equal option.

[image]

the first slicer will return data of employee start working at 2022,

but the second slicer with return data of employee start working in or **before** 2022.

I want to synchronize the value from the first slicer to the second.

thank you